# Excel - If then index match if

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have columns A, B, and C. Column D will be the new column that adds the spouse's name if found. The common information between the contacts is the address, so here's the formula I have so far:

```
=IF(B3="Spouse", IF(INDEX(B:B, MATCH(C3,C:C, 0))="Primary", INDEX(A:A, MATCH(C3,C:C, 0)), ""), "No Spouse")
```

The issue seems to be with `MATCH(C3,C:C, 0)`. The `C3` cell is finding itself in the `C:C` range.

```
   A                B              C                  D
Name             Relationship    Address             Spouse
Joe Smith        Primary         432 Park Dr         No Spouse
Michael Turner   Primary         2298 Thompson Rd    No spouse
Sarah Smith      Spouse          432 Park Dr         Joe Smith
Hannah Smith     Child           432 Park Dr         No Spouse
```

Comment: Try using the `=IF(AND())` relationship

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this formula:

```
=IF(B2="Spouse","",IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($C$2:$C$4)/(($C$2:$C$4=C2)*($A$2:$A$4<>A2)),1)),"No Spouse"))
```

[image]

---

As per your new data:

```
=IF(B2="Spouse",IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($C$2:$C$5)/(($C$2:$C$5=C2)*($A$2:$A$5<>A2)*($B$2:$B$5 = "Primary")),1)),"No Spouse"),"No Spouse")
```

[image]

Comment: one day, Scott might retire from S.O. ; until then, the Excel tag is in a stranglehold

Comment: @DavidAndreiNed hey, I waited 9 minutes to post.  I gave people a fighting chance. :)

Comment: yup, waited a little while,  took me longer to make the example than to write the formula.  I wrote the formula in the answer box first.  Then created the example.

Comment: I haven't tried yet, but I'm not sure if this would work in my case. I updated the original entry. There are children who share the same address, so I assume this will need to check if "Primary". Also, not all spouses share the same last name.

Comment: @ScottCraner I just get "No Spouse". I have over 5000 rows. Without knowing much about excel, is your formula limiting to five rows?

Comment: yes, you need to expand the references to the full dataset.

Comment: @JoshKern please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Comment: @ScottCraner How can I account for empty cells? Some of the address fields are empty, so I don't want to connect a Spouse with an empty cell to a Primary with an empty cell. I noticed this happened to a few contacts.

Answer (score 0):

Alternate formula for backwards compatibility (in cell D2 and copied down):

```
=IF(OR(COUNTIF(C:C,C2)=1,B2="Child"),"No Spouse",INDEX($A$2:$A$4,MATCH(1,INDEX(($C$2:$C$4=C2)*($A$2:$A$4<>A2),),0)))
```

Comment: I also have other relationships values: Adult, Grandchild, and Partner